# Why do I see a screen showing all text I typed during the session on logging out?

Tags: security, password, logout

When I log off of Ubuntu 12.10, a screen appears shortly with all the text I typed during the session, including passwords and such.

Is this supposed to happen?

[update]
The screen is fullscreen black with white text. I am running Ubuntu as a guest OS within VMWare 5.0.1 on a Windows 7 64bit system.

I'm not sure what software I installed other than Google Chrome and GNOME 3 Classic user interface.

Comment: This is certainly *not* supposed to happen. Keystrokes should not be recorded and sounds really suspicious to me. However, your question does not list any details, which makes it very hard to answer. What kind of screen is this? What software did you install after installing Ubuntu? Keep in mind that we can't see your screen and we don't have access to your PC. We rely on the *specific* information you provide in your question.

Comment: I added a little more info. Is there more that you need?

Comment: It's still very vague to me. Would it be possible to provide a series of screenshots or a video? Since you're running it virtual this should be really trivial! :)

Comment: Can you use your smartphone or something to actually record a short video of this? It's hard to tell from your description what it looks like.

Comment: I couldn't get it to happen again. It just looks like a terminal window with a black screen with lots of text and each sentence I typed on a new line. Will try again tomorrow.

Comment: This isn't a keylogger. I had a fresh install on which I was messing around with GNOME 3. I uninstalled it, and was using Unity.   The black screen thing happened quite a few times. My guess is that the keyboard driver logs its output somewhere.